# Can we make a loaded page load a different page to an element in the first page using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, load

I want to make an element load a page when an event in another loaded page is triggered. I think the problem is the loaded page would not recognized the element from the page that load it. Is there any solutions? Here is my code:

Page1.php:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".class1").load("page2.php"); 
    });
    </script>
    <div class="class1"></div>
    <div class="classfrompage1"></div>
```

Page2.php:

```
$(".btnpage2").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            //Some ajax code to write to database
            success:function(data){                 
            $(".classfrompage1").load("page3.php");
            }
        });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in which page is `.btnpage2` ?

Comment: try using this on page 2 `$(document).on("click",".btnpage2",function(){
        $.ajax({
            success:function(data){                 
            $(".classfrompage1").load("page3.php");
            }
        });
});`

Comment: It is in the second page

Comment: alternatives are to pass the code you have in page 2 to the callback function of `load` in page 1

Comment: Does it work with element from ajax .html() ?

Comment: Yes it does. This syntax `$(document).on("type-of-event","#elementID or .elementClass",function(){` can be used for any element loaded dynamically. You just have to be precise where to place your code, i mean sometimes when using ajax you have to place events inside the success callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you content loads dynamically you could try

```
$(document).on("click",".btnpage2",function(){ 
  $.ajax({ success:function(data){ 
  //Some ajax code to write to database
    $(".classfrompage1").load("page3.php"); 
    } 
  }); 
});
```

alternatives are to pass the code you have in page 2 to the callback function of load in page 1